# IE 11 is detected as IE 7.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to detect my user's browsers and I want to stop all IE versions that are < 10. That's why I have created 2 different methods and both are doing the same: The first one is relying on userAgent and the second is relying on Browser name and version:

```
Public Function DetectBrowser() As Boolean

        Dim accept As Boolean = True
        Dim version As Integer = 0
        'Dim userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent

        'Dim MSIE = userAgent.IndexOf("MSIE ")

        'If MSIE > 0 Then
        '    ' IE 10 or older 
        '    Dim cutteduserAgent = userAgent.Substring(MSIE + 5)
        '    version = Integer.Parse(cutteduserAgent.Substring(0, cutteduserAgent.IndexOf(".")), 10)
        '    If version < 10 Then
        '        accept = False
        '        ' Else case will be true as it is defined by default 
        '    End If
        'End If

        Dim browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser
        If browser = "IE" Then
            version = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Version
            If version < 10 Then
                accept = False
            End If
        End If


        DetectBrowser = accept

 End Function
```

I am using this method in my default.aspx page, if this method returns false then user is redirected to the OutdatedBrowser.aspx page, else user will be redirected to login page. In addition of that I have added the browser name and version to be displayed in outdatedBrowser.aspx page. But I was chocked when one of my users sent me this picture

[image: this picture]

If he clicks on "About Internet Explorer" a popup appears displaying version 11 of IE. But as you can see (the black sentence in the bottom) that my code has detected "browser: IE Version: 7.0" instead of "browser: Mozilla Version: 0.0"

I have tried both methods above and both are redirecting this user to the outdatedBrowser.aspx page. What could be the problem and how can I fix it? I have IE 11 and I have never encountered this problem ...

Comment: Compatibility View for Intranet sites maybe? Check your IE settings.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day

Comment: Glad to help. We have all be there - IE and its funny default settings.

Comment: Isn't `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Version` a `String` whereas [HttpCapabilitiesBase.MajorVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.majorversion(v=vs.110).aspx) is an `Integer`.

Comment: @TnTinMn is right. It is a string. You need to parse first.